# Make scrapyd overwrite files

Tags: curl, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm looking for a way to set up a job in scrapyd, which creates a file locally and then overwrites its content at the next crawl, instead of appending it.
As far as I know, using scrapy only I could use this command

```
scrapy crawl myspider -t json --nolog -o - > "/path/to/json/my.json"
```

but there seems no way to set up these arguments in scrapyd, or in curl command line (which i use to set up scrapyd).

Comment: @Guillaume and Umair: solved with both suggestions. I extended FileFeedStorage and, after that, I had to set up a Scheduled Task (I am in Windows 10) with the curl command that runs every 30 seconds. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own feed storage. Extend the scrapy's `FileFeedStorage`, overwrite the `open` method to return a file in write mode (scrapy's `FileFeedStorage` returns a file in append mode).

```
import os

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.extensions.feedexport import FileFeedStorage

class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'toscrape.com'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(('quotes.toscrape.com/page/',)), callback='parsePage', follow=True),
    )

    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_STORAGES': {
            'file': 'myspider.MyFileFeedStorage'
        },
        'FEED_URI': 'file:///my/valid/file/path/out.json'
    }

    def parsePage(self, response):
        return ({
            'quote': quote.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first(),
            'author': quote.xpath('.//small[@class="author"]/text()').extract_first(), 
        } for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'))

class MyFileFeedStorage(FileFeedStorage):

    def open(self, spider):
        dirname = os.path.dirname(self.path)
        if dirname and not os.path.exists(dirname):
            os.makedirs(dirname)
        return open(self.path, 'wb')
```

If you run `scrapy runspider myspider.py` multiple times, you will see that the output file is recreated each time (assuming your script is named `myspider.py`).

Answer (score 0):

How are you sceduling spider using ScrapyD? via a Cron? or what?

I have 2 ideas,

1) Empty file manually before sending command to scrapyd,

```
echo "" > /path/to/json/my.json && curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json
```

This will clear contents of `my.json` first and then will schedule spider.

2) inside your spider, just do

```
open("/path/to/json/my.json", 'w').close()
```